# Add divs to post content with Advanced Custom Fields plug in? (wordpress)

Tags: html, plugins, wordpress

I was wondering if it's possible, I tried making a custom field type a Text Area (under Basic) with [Advance Custom Fields](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/&ei=qIEBUu_kGMv40gWVvICIDg&usg=AFQjCNGFjp_dopkb9s2TIG2uwk1WPjsiGw&sig2=NhRcs-Mmp0C_K8RRdsYIgg&bvm=bv.50310824,d.d2k) plugin, with the default value having  which I assigned a css attribute of 200x200px with a background of green, this did not appear on the post when viewed from the front end however so I was wondering if it's actually possible and how to do it properly.

Comment: please at least show us some code

Comment: cover your textarea with a `<div class="txtArea_name"></div>` then target `.txtArea_name textarea{/*your css styles*/}`